# MacBook cannot reach the router after a few minutes

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have one Windows PC, three Macs and some iPhone and Android phone devices. However, only one MacBook Pro starts to have Wi-Fi problems after few minutes of connectivity.

The Wi-Fi symbol in menu bar shows 'connected', but I am unable to ping the router.

Also, this issue only happens at home. This problem MacBook works fine outside my apartment.

Any references on how can I debug it?

Comment: Does the router also provide some diagnostics?

Answer (score 0):

Option-click on the Wi-Fi Menu Extra and select `Open Wireless Diagnostics…`.

You should follow the diagnostic assistant screens, but also check the menus for the other diagnostic tools as well.